# Como posicionar uma div na frente de outra

Tags: html, css

Tentei da seguinte forma, mas não funcionou... continua com a de baixo ficando em cima da de cima, quando deveria ser o contrário. O que estou fazendo errado?

```
.funil{
    text-align:center;
}
.funil_1 { 
    margin-bottom:-20px;
    z-index:4;
}
.funil_2 { 
    margin-bottom:-15px;
    z-index:3;
}
.funil_3 { 
    margin-bottom:-10px;
    z-index:2;
}
.funil_4 { 
    z-index:1;
}

<div class='posts-container funil'>
    <div class="funil_1"><img src="/images/funil_1.png"></div>
    <div class="funil_2"><img src="/images/funil_2.png"></div>
    <div class="funil_3"><img src="/images/funil_3.png"></div>
    <div class="funil_4"><img src="/images/funil_4.png"></div>
</div>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`z-index` só funciona para elementos com a posição determinada.

Especifique a posição dos elementos para que funcione... :)

```
.funil div {
    position: relative;  //(position:absolute, position:relative, ou position:fixed).
}
```

Comment: funcionou, obrigado!